# How to Import a transparent .SVG file to blender, and convert it to a 3D object?

Tags: svg

Hi friendly and helpfull people in here!
I have a problem I am trying to solve for my company I am working at. The project is to make this pattern done in illustrator: https://we.tl/sr516OF9mD , to a 3D object I can wrap around the top of a 3D tin-basket. But when I import the .SVG file into illustrator, it keeps messing up with weird faces so I can't use the curve modifier, to wrap it around in a circle curve. 
[image: Preview]

I have tried to go through the illustrator file, and fix the points, so the path is closed, and there is no gabs in the structure of the 2D shape, but it still seem to come out wrong when I import it to blender. 
I hope someone can help me with this issue, because it is something we will do more often in the future at my job.

Thank you in advance and Kind Regards
-Anders

Answer (score 1):

I've made two things in Illustrator and it was imported correctly:

- Select your shape and, in the *Pathfinder* window, click the *Unite* tool.
- Scale it very big (like 1000%)

then save and, in Blender, *Import* > *SVG*.

To make it a mesh: Select the object and *alt C* > *Mesh From Curve*

You can simplify the mesh a lot in Edit mode with *X* > *Limited Dissolve*, and *W* > *Remove Doubles*

It will display black even if you apply a white material but you can change it in the *Properties* > *Material* > *Settings* > *Viewport Colors*